SQL (Oracle or Teradata) assign state to customer based on where they buy the most
Consider table structured like



CustomerNum
state
sales_volume




1
NJ
5000


1
NY
25


5
WA
1250


5
OR
85


5
MN
3100



How would I produce output that tacks on a "winning" state by
customer based on state with cutomer's most sales? (I know I might need to deal with tie breaking.)



CustomerNum
state
sales_volume
StateMax




1
NJ
5000
NJ


1
NY
25
NJ


5
WA
1250
MN


5
OR
85
MN


5
MN
3100
MN



My main DB is teradata, but Oracle input (or ANSI SQL) might help to know.  I don't know if I can do it with windowing in Teradata?  The data source is of course nowhere near as simple as the example.  In fact it's a multi-table join which is why ideally I wouldn't even bring in a subquery and Teradata window functions are of interest.  I mean yes I could do a subquery but I'm hoping to learn something more elegant that is done "inline".
I don't know how to label each customer with their max sales state and still keep the data at customer level using some kind of inline windowing (or windowing like) statement.

Sounds like FIRST_VALUE / LAST_VALUE

SELECT CustomerNum, state, sales_volume, FIRST_VALUE(State) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY sales_volume DESC) as StateMax should get you in the ballpark.

In Oracle, you can use:
SELECT t.*,
       MIN(state)
         KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sales_volume)
         OVER (PARTITION BY customernum) AS statemax
FROM   table_name t

or, equivalently:
SELECT t.*,
       FIRST_VALUE(state)
         OVER (PARTITION BY customernum
               ORDER BY sales_volume DESC, state) AS statemax
FROM   table_name t

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (CustomerNum, state, sales_volume) AS
SELECT 1, 'NJ', 5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'NY',   25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'WA', 1250 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'OR',   85 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'MN', 3100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'NJ', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'NY',  900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'AK', 1000 FROM DUAL;

Both output:



CUSTOMERNUM
STATE
SALES_VOLUME
STATEMAX




1
NJ
5000
NJ


1
NY
25
NJ


5
MN
3100
MN


5
WA
1250
MN


5
OR
85
MN


6
AK
1000
AK


6
NJ
1000
AK


6
NY
900
AK



If you want to output all the states when there is a tie for the maximum sales_volume then:
SELECT customernum,
       state,
       sales_volume,
       LISTAGG(
         CASE rnk WHEN 1 THEN state END,
         ','
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY state)
         OVER (PARTITION BY customernum) AS statemax
FROM   (
  SELECT customernum,
         state,
         sales_volume,
         DENSE_RANK()
           OVER (PARTITION BY customernum ORDER BY sales_volume DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name
)

Which outputs:



CUSTOMERNUM
STATE
SALES_VOLUME
STATEMAX




1
NJ
5000
NJ


1
NY
25
NJ


5
MN
3100
MN


5
OR
85
MN


5
WA
1250
MN


6
AK
1000
AK,NJ


6
NJ
1000
AK,NJ


6
NY
900
AK,NJ



fiddle

And the FIRST_VALUE query is also ANSI/ISO SQL compliant, using the optional features T617, 'FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE functions', and
T611, 'Elementary OLAP operations'.

Thx @. Today I learned about the existence of FIRST_VALUE / LAST_VALUE.  Teradata also has those functions, though it doesn't look like KEEP is part of the syntax.  My understanding is KEEP is like the father of the groom at a wedding - expected to be there, but doesn't do anything.

@TrippKnightly Saying that KEEP doesn't do anything is wrong - fiddle is an example showing the difference betwen using and not-using KEEP.
